# Valor null en datos obtenidos de JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un script que recupera la información de un JSON como puedo poner para que si no tiene nada el JSON no ponga nada en la variable `items`. Este es mi código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#IdPlantel").change(function () {
                $.getJSON("Oferta/List/" + $("#IdPlantel>option:selected").attr("value"), function (data) {
                    var items;
                    if (data == null) {// no lo respeta
                        items = "";
                    }
                    else {
                        $.each(data, function (i, state) {
                            items += "<option value='" + state.Value + "'>" + state.Text + "</option>";
                        });
                    }

                    $("#States").html(items);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que la respuesta de `Ofeta/List/...` es null, y no una cadena vacía?

Comment: puede provar esto if ( data.length == 0 ) {// tu codigo} saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dudo que un servidor devuelva una respuesta nula. Lo más probable es que el servidor mande una respuesta vacía. Por tanto, intenta evaluando si `data` es una cadena vacía. Esta es una manera:

```
if (data === "") {
    //...
} else ...
```

Otra forma:

```
if (data.length === 0) {
    //...
} else ...
```

En caso que quieras evaluar si `data` es nulo, utiliza esta evaluación:

```
if (data) {
    //...
} else ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes checar de la siguiente manera con `JavaScript` puro.

```
if ( data.length == 0 ) {
     console.log("NO HAY DATOS!")
}
```

o tambien puedes utilizar `jQuery`, de la siguiente manera:

```
if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(data))
{
    console.log("objeto Vacío");
}
```

espero te funcione, saludos.